# How to run .jl file from command line

Tags: julia

This command does not work:

```
julia --project=. ./example/polynomials.jl
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: @polyvar not defined
in expression starting at /home/<redacted>/TSSOS/example/polynomials.jl:4
in expression starting at /home/<redacted>/TSSOS/example/polynomials.jl:4
```

from: https://github.com/wangjie212/TSSOS/blob/master/example/polynomials.jl

How do I get it to work?

Update: Tried this too

```
julia> using TSSOS

julia> using DynamicPolynomials

julia> include("example/polynomials.jl")
┌ Warning: Assignment to `f` in soft scope is ambiguous because a global variable by the same name exists: `f` will be treated as a new local. Disambiguate by using `local f` to suppress this warning or `global f` to assign to the existing global variable.
└ @ ~/improbable/TSSOS/example/polynomials.jl:16
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: f not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ ~/improbable/TSSOS/example/polynomials.jl:16
 [2] include(fname::String)
   @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:476
 [3] top-level scope
   @ REPL[3]:1
in expression starting at /home/<redacted>/TSSOS/example/polynomials.jl:15
```

Comment: It seems to expect some package or module to have been loaded, something that exports the `@polyvar` macro. It was probably intended to be `include`d after doing so.

Comment: What am I supposed to type?

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting I run

Comment: I'm not sure what to do, the rather scant documentation does not say which package the macro is from, exactly. The examples seem to imply `@polyvar` exists after `using TSSOS, DynamicPolynomials` at least, but I cannot tell if there's some other thing that needs another module further in the source file.

Comment: I updated my post with another thing I tried

Comment: No offense to the coders but they did not do their due diligence, though this pothole is also due to language design. In source files and `eval`ed expressions, you're supposed to declare `global f` inside local scopes like for-loops if you reassign it there; it helps prevent accidental reassignments among multiple `include`d source files. But when they made that rule in v1.0, people complained, so they made "soft scopes" where you didn't need the declaration when you work in the REPL or a notebook (not `eval`/`include`-able). The coders copied from a notebook into a .jl file, didn't adjust.

Comment: So do you have a suggestion for how to get it to work?

Comment: Just fixing the code to import the necessary packages and adding all the global declarations in the for loops. You could surround the whole thing in a locally scoped let block, I suppose, it'll work as it is there. Thing is, what do you plan by running this at the command line, the script won't save or display anything. Do you want to start up the REPL too so you can interact with the global variables?

Answer (score 1):

This is a patchy answer, but it works on my laptop:

```
include_string(Main, 
  "using TSSOS, DynamicPolynomials\nfunction main()\n"*
  String(read("example/polynomials.jl"))*
  "\nreturn pop\nend\n\nmain()\n",
  "fixed_polynomials.jl")
```

Basically, this patches the file to do the right `using` statements upfront and define the example as a function, which is called. A return value for the `main` function is added to have some output (not sure what the desired output is).